# Conversion of liquid rennet to powdered rennet?

Tags: cheese, cheese-making

How much powdered rennet should you use if a recipe states 1 tsp liquid rennet (for cheese)?

Answer (score 1):

1 ml of liquid rennet is more or less equivalent to 0.12 grams.

So 1 tsp is 5 ml; which should equivalent to 0.6 g powdered rennet, or 1 rennet tablet.